# White borders left out after moving the axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, axes

I'm trying to make the matplotlib graph look more like the ones used in graphing calculators. When moving the axes to the center of the plot, the place they used to be is left empty, making it look like it has white borders.

[NORMAL GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii0Ug.png)

[MODIFIED GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO0SK.png)

I don't know if this is related to the axes or to the labels which were removed.

I am aware of an argument used when saving the image, something like

`plt.savefig("image.png",bbox_inches='tight')`

but regardless of whether that method works for this situation or for other kind of borders, my intention is to show the image inside a tkinter window, not saving it to the users computer.

Is there a way of removing these left out "borders"?

Here's the code

```
from tkinter import * 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import random
import numpy as np

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

# CREATE X VALUES
x_list = np.arange(-20, 20, .01)

# GENERATE 'RANDOM' VALUES FOR THE QUADRATIC EQUATION'S PARAMETERS
a = random.choice([-1,-0.6,0.6,1])
b = random.uniform(-5,5)
c = random.randint(-5,5)

# CREATE FIGURE
fig = Figure(figsize = (5, 5), dpi = 100)

# PLOT 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x_list, a * np.power(x_list,2) + b * x_list + c)
ax.axis([-20,20,-20,20])

# CENTER TWO AXES
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')

# HIDE THE OTHER TWO AXES
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

# SET TICKS POSITION
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

# HIDE NUMBER LABELS
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])

# -------------------------- COLORS
# I want to remove the green part of the figure
# (UNCOMMENT TO SEE THE COLORS IN THE FIGURE)
#fig.set_facecolor('#68C45F')
#ax.set_facecolor('#E56361')

# CREATE CANVAS
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)  
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I just found out that you can use fig.tight_layout() to decrease these borders.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

```
hereimport numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Select length of axes and the space between tick labels
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = -5, 5, -5, 5
ticks_frequency = 1

# Plot points
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

#////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)

y = x**2 - 1
plt.plot(x, y, color = "red", alpha = 0.8, lw = 1)

#//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

# Set identical scales for both axes
ax.set(xlim=(xmin-1, xmax+1), ylim=(ymin-1, ymax+1), aspect='equal')

# Set bottom and left spines as x and y axes of coordinate system
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')

# Remove top and right spines
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

# Create 'x' and 'y' labels placed at the end of the axes
ax.set_xlabel('x', size=14, labelpad=-24, x=1.03)
ax.set_ylabel('y', size=14, labelpad=-21, y=1.02, rotation=0)

# Create custom major ticks to determine position of tick labels
x_ticks = np.arange(xmin, xmax+1, ticks_frequency)
y_ticks = np.arange(ymin, ymax+1, ticks_frequency)
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks[x_ticks != 0])
ax.set_yticks(y_ticks[y_ticks != 0])

# Create minor ticks placed at each integer to enable drawing of minor grid
# lines: note that this has no effect in this example with ticks_frequency=1
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax+1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(ymin, ymax+1), minor=True)

# Draw major and minor grid lines
ax.grid(which='both', color='grey', linewidth=1, linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)

# Draw arrows
arrow_fmt = dict(markersize=4, color='black', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((1), (0), marker='>', transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), **arrow_fmt)
ax.plot((0), (1), marker='^', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), **arrow_fmt)

plt.show()
```

here you have a nice looking graph i hope that helps